# How to make an image change when pressed on a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

My goal is to make the "down-arrow.svg" change to "up-arrow.svg" if the image was "down-arrow.svg" when clicked on the upper div which contains this image and versa via.

I have looked up the past questions and answers, found something but they couldn't solve my problem, these index.html and index.js files grows from one of the answers written here. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

index.html:

```
<head>
    <title> Some Title </title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
...
    <div id="open-menu" onClick=changeArrow() >
        <div id="open-menu-inner" >
            <p id="open-menu-text" > Menü </p>
            <img id="up-down-arrow" src="svg/down-arrow.svg" >
        </div>
    </div>
...
</body>
```

index.js:

```
function changeArrow() {
    if (document.getElementById("up-down-arrow").src == "svg/down-arrow.svg") {
        document.getElementById("up-down-arrow").src = "svg/up-arrow.svg";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("up-down-arrow").src = "svg/down-arrow.svg";
    }
}
```

stylesheet.css:

```
div#open-menu {
    height: 50px;
    width: 90%;
    border: 2px solid rgba(94, 94, 94, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 180px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

div#open-menu-inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table;
}

p#open-menu-text {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #5e5e5e;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}

img#up-down-arrow {
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console? You're missing quotes in `onClick=changeArrow()`

Comment: and it is `onclick=changeArrow()''` instead of `onClick=changeArrow()`..

Comment: `img.src` is **absolute** path. Use `img.src.indexOf('down')>-1` or `img.getAttribute('src')=='svg/down-arrow.svg'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change your image source and not the ID of it.

So with your HTML structure i can guide you with changing just the ID of the `img`  tag.

The Solution is as below:

```js
function changeArrow() {
  //First grabing the current Source in below varaiable.
  var img = document.getElementById('arrowSvg').src;
  
  /*
  ** Now checking if it does match with path that we have in variable.
  ** And updating src based on the current src of image.
  */
  if (img.indexOf('svg/down-arrow.svg') != -1) {
    document.getElementById('arrowSvg').src = 'svg/up-arrow.svg';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('arrowSvg').src = 'svg/down-arrow.svg';
  }
}
```

```css
div#open-menu {
  height: 50px;
  width: 90%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(94, 94, 94, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 180px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

div#open-menu-inner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table;
}

p#open-menu-text {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #5e5e5e;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
}

img#up-down-arrow {
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="open-menu" onClick=changeArrow()>
  <div id="open-menu-inner">
    <p id="open-menu-text"> Menü </p>
    <img id="arrowSvg" src="svg/down-arrow.svg">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Hope this helps you.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue should be in your paths, with images from Google it works fine:

```js
function changeArrow() {
    if (document.getElementById("up-down-arrow").src == "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/242277-200.png") {
        document.getElementById("up-down-arrow").src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/37/Octicons-arrow-small-up.svg/1000px-Octicons-arrow-small-up.svg.png";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("up-down-arrow").src = "https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/242277-200.png";
    }
}
```

```css
div#open-menu {
    height: 50px;
    width: 90%;
    border: 2px solid rgba(94, 94, 94, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 180px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

div#open-menu-inner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table;
}

p#open-menu-text {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #5e5e5e;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}

img#up-down-arrow {
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title> Some Title </title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="open-menu" onClick=changeArrow() >
        <div id="open-menu-inner" >
            <p id="open-menu-text" > Menü </p>
            <img id="up-down-arrow" src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/242277-200.png" >
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
document.getElementById("up-down-arrow").src
```

with

```
document.getElementById("up-down-arrow").getAttribute('src')
```

- **src** returns the full URL of the image
- **getAttribute('src')** returns exactly what was in the HTML, i.e. the way that you wrote it

ps. I would also like to suggest a few potential improvements to your current HTML page:

- I would recommend moving the JS import from the head to the bottom of the body tag just before closing it. This will make sure that the body of your webpage will render before downloading the JS file which will make the page render faster to your end users.
- (This is because the way that the browser renders html is it executes
  it line by line which means that it will stop to download the javascript file before executing anything else that comes after it, i.e. displaying the body of the webpage to the user.)
- I would also recommend replacing the inline onClick function with an eventListener inside of your JS file that way you will have separation between your HTML and JS files which will make your website more maintainable as it grows in size
- Depending on the size of your DOM it MIGHT also be faster to store, i.e. cache, the "up-down-arrow" node inside of a variable to avoid the performance cost of querying for that node inside of the DOM each time the user clicks on it, i.e.

  ```
  $up_down_arrow = document.getElementById("up-down-arrow");

  if ($up_down_arrow.getAttribute('src') === "bin2-lighter.svg") {
      $up_down_arrow.setAttribute('src', 'bin2-darker.svg')
  } else {
      $up_down_arrow.setAttribute('src', 'bin2-lighter.svg');
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you may use classList.toggle instead. The idea of `toggle` is it will add the class if it's not present on the element, and remove it if it's present. It will be more optimize as well. Put the images into the class and toggle that class onClick so as the example below; see `arrow-up` on css and how it is used in `toggle` in javascript section. Initially the `<div id="arrow"..` has already an `arrow` class that's why you will see an arrow down icon, when the toggle is triggered, the element will become like this `<div id="arrow" class="arrow arrow-up"></div>` and this `<div id="arrow" class="arrow"></div>` alternatively. The toggling of `arrow-up` class gives the effect of changing arrow icons.

```js
function changeArrow() {
  var element = document.getElementById("arrow");
     element.classList.toggle("arrow-up");
}
```

```css
.open-menu {
 padding: 20px;
 position: absolute;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #000000;
}

.arrow {
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
 background: url('http://www.entypo.com/images/chevron-down.svg') no-repeat;
}

.arrow-up {
 background: url('http://www.entypo.com/images/chevron-up.svg') no-repeat !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="open-menu" onClick="changeArrow()" >
 <div id="arrow" class="arrow"></div>
</div>
```

*image's used on sample copyright to www.entypo.com*